# Trouble with text alignment in nested bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to present name, phone and email like this:

```
| Joe Shmoe           |       555-555-5555 |
|                     |      joe@shmoe.net |
```

And when the name get's too long, I want to wrap like this:

```
| Josephine           |       555-555-5555 |
| Hosssenpfefer       |     jfine@mail.net |
```

And when the email get's too long, I want to overflow like this:

```
| Joe Shmoe           |       555-555-5555 |
|               someverylongemail@mail.net |
```

I created this html, which defines a row with two half-width columns.  The right hand column has two nested rows, and each of those nested rows has a full width column...

```
<div class="row">
  <h5 class="col-xs-6 list-group-item-heading">Joe Shmoe</h5>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-xs-12 list-group-item-text text-right">555-555-5555</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-xs-12 list-group-item-text text-right" style="color:navy">joe@shmoe.net</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This almost works, [but as you can see in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddledan/rk69yrq4/), the bottom nested row won't right-align.  (You might need to make the view narrow to see the problem).

I'd like it right aligned just like the nested row above it.  Furthermore, when the content is long, I'd like that content (not wrapped) to overflow on the left side, spilling into the left column if necessary.

Can someone give advice?  Thanks!

Comment: So you want all the content on the left half of the page?

Comment: @MortHub - yes, everything that doesn't fit ending at the right edge of the right column.

Comment: @BeNdErR - works!  Much obliged.  Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a table for this.  It might need additional styling, but find tables make it easier to handle the longer characters.  Is this at all on the right track?

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <table class="table">
  <tr class=""><td class="col-xs-6">Joe Shmoe</td><td class="col-xs-6 text-right">555 555-5555</td></tr>
  <tr class=""><td class="col-xs-6"></td><td class="col-xs-6 text-right">somereallylongemailaddress@reallylongemail.com</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, but just adding direction: rtl did the trick.  Thanks.